# Проверить наличие поста по его ид на странице пользователя Facebook

Tags: api, facebook

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно проверить наличие поста по его ид на странице пользователя Facebook, используя их API?

Пробовал так GET /v2.12/post-id HTTP/1.1 Host: graph.facebook.com, где вместо post-id указывал ид поста, но не работает, возвращается "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher".

Comment: По ошибке видно, что нужно использовать запрос из версии 2.4 или вышел, а вы используете 2.12

Comment: Исходя из ошибки нужно использовать наоборот версию ниже 2.4 (2.12 выше 2.4), но в Graph API Explorer нельзя выбрать версию ниже 2.5. И вообще получается, что в новой версии апи нельзя получить пост по его ид?